# Why is g++/ld running out of memory?

Tags: c++, qt, g++, mingw, ld

I am trying to compile Qt (Windows 7, mingw32-g++ 32-bit under msys) and ld is running out of memory. Does anyone know why? Or perhaps a workaround? Thanks!

```
$ g++ -mthreads -shared -Wl,--out-implib,i:/Programs/Qt/lib/libQtGuid4.a -o ../
../lib/QtGuid4.dll object_script.QtGuid.Debug  -L'i:/Programs/Qt/lib' -L'i:/Pro
grams/Qt/lib' -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -loleaut32 -limm32 -lwinmm -lwinspool -lws2_32
 -lole32 -luuid -luser32 -ladvapi32 tmp/obj/debug_shared/QtGuid_resource_res.o
-lmsimg32 -lshell32 -lQtCored4 -lz

i:/programs/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: o
ut of memory allocating 133614056 bytes
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Do you have enough memory in the first place? 130 MB isn't really a lot...

Comment: @Mysticial the system has 16GB of memory, the process was at about 2gb of memory when it crashed.

Comment: Sounds like the compiler is running in 32-bit mode. That'll cap it at 2GB on Windows. Have you tried 64-bit?

Comment: The system is a 64 bit system, the problem is that ld is a 32 bit process. how can i workaround that?

Comment: It's possible to let a 32-bit process use up to 3GB in Windows. But you need to recompile it with the right options. I assume the `ld` that you have is out of the box, so this probably isn't an option.

Comment: yea, its the standard ld/gcc included with mingw

Comment: [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) has a 64-bit toolchain.

Comment: @Mystical: a Large Address Aware application will get up to nearly 4GB of address space on WOW64 systems (not just the 3GB that was available on specially configured 32-bit systems).

Comment: What version of Qt?  I just recently built 4.7.3 successfully with a similar system (Win7 x64 using a 32-bit MinGW 4.6.1 - the TDM distribution). I don't have any suggestions, but am wondering if the Qt version might be a factor (note that the ld.exe I have is not Large Address Aware, so it's limited to 2GB of address space).

Comment: If you're adventurous, you might try making `ld.exe` large address aware using `editbin /largeaddressaware ld.exe` - editbin comes with the Microsoft C/C++ toolchain, maybe it's in the SDK as well. This will make 4GB available to the process, but if the program has bugs dealing with pointers that have the high bit set (a common problem, which is why there's a special bit in the image's header to enable the feature) you might just run into other problems. So make a backup copy of `ld.exe` to revert to if necessary.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=28485608 there are a couple of suggestions here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to all the commenters who helped me figure out a solution to this problem. What I did was replace `ld` with a large address aware version. I downloaded it from [this](https://pcxprj.googlecode.com/files/MinGW64CRT_gcc4.6.3pre_static_win32.7z) MinGW build inside the bin folder. The post with the person linking that distribution is [here](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=28487743). I hope this helps other people who run into this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you install the current version of MinGW 4.6 or newer, then compile QT should specify the flag:

configure -platform win32-g++-4.6

In "mkspecs" for win32-g++4.6 already defined flag -fno-keep-inline-dllexport which resolves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to download ld.exe from somewhere else, but it was not fitting into my toolkit (TDM-GCC). Some plugin was not able to load. Hopefully, making ld.exe LAA was not that hard. I have opened ld.exe in a hex editor and patched at offset 0x96 "0f 03" to "2f 03". That did the trick for me.